# Synonymize [AutoHotKey] and [AHK]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

AutoHotKey, often abbreviated "AHK", appears to have at least 2 different tags: the main [autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey) tag, and the abbreviated [ahk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ahk) tag.

I propose making [ahk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ahk) a synonym of [autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey).

Answer (score 3):

```
updating post history, 7 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 6 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 2 rows affected
destroying 'ahk': [ahk] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for master tag, new count: 2997
tag remapping of [autohotkey] and [ahk] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
113 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym ahk -> autohotkey was approved!
```